# Obter id de objetos SVG

Tags: javascript

Consigo obter o *id* de um objecto SVG através do `getElementById` usando apenas um.

Mas como tenho 3 objectos, como posso saber o *id* de cada um.

```js
var shape = document.getElementById('rect1');

shape.onclick = function(){
       alert(this.id);
    };
```

```html
<svg width=90% height=500px>
    <rect id="rect1" ry=0 rx=0 x=50 y=50 width=20px height=20px fill=red />
 
 <rect id="rect2" ry=0 rx=0 x=80 y=50 width=20px height=20px fill=blue />
 
 <rect id="rect3" ry=0 rx=0 x=110 y=50 width=20px height=20px fill=green />
</svg>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zr1gzL5f/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um modo de fazer isso é usar `getElementsByTagName` e percorrer os elementos num `for`.

```js
var shapes = document.getElementsByTagName('rect');

for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
    shapes[i].addEventListener('click', showID, false);
}
function showID(){
    alert(this.id);
}
```

```html
<svg width=90% height=500px>
    <rect id="rect1" ry=0 rx=0 x=50 y=50 width=20px height=20px fill=red />
 
 <rect id="rect2" ry=0 rx=0 x=80 y=50 width=20px height=20px fill=blue />
 
 <rect id="rect3" ry=0 rx=0 x=110 y=50 width=20px height=20px fill=green />
</svg>
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e1m9wkt9/)</kbd>